# Custom initialisers with nib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am creating a custom UICustomView that is a subview of UIView.  I can create a custom designated initialiser in it that will ask for a delegate and datasource. But this will only be called when a control consumer will create the control programatically.

However, I'd like to provide basic layout support, ie. it  should be possible to place an empty UIView into any NIB file, an then change its class in Identity Inspector to a UICustomView. In similar manner as you can place other stock Apple controls into the nib.

But how will then I be able to force the consumer to provide a delegate and a datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to use custom initializers from a nib file.  Most commonly, views that require data sources and delegates get wired up using IBOutlet properties in the view class, or their properties are set in the view controller before the view is rendered.

If you want to force the consumer to provide a delegate and data source, you can always put an assert in the `-viewDidLoad` method and make sure they've been wired up (and handle the right protocols while you're at it).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do what you want by using initWithCoder:. That will be called for views coming out of a xib or storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

As @gaige said,  Just take the IBOutlet properties in your custom view class for dataSource and delegate. Also you can provide the designated initializer for setting those values while creating programmatically. If outlet properties are there you can wire up them in interface builder as we do with normal TableViews.

Answer (score 0):

I think tha most common and rapid way to solve your problem is to customize the viewDidLoad method Initializing the property of the class in the viewdidload method of the controller associated with your view.